# populating SELECT from XML for live search

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Please help me with this. I have an xml file like this

```
<ProjectList>
  <ProjectName>AAJ</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>hjgg</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>asfasf</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>qwere</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>sadaf</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>asd</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>asad</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>wildzike</ProjectName>
  <ProjectName>yahoo</ProjectName>
</ProjectList>
```

I need a search box in php for a live search. I got solution from this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp to create that search box. But here it is not convenient since no option for selecting the values using arrow keys. I think it would be better replacing the search text field with drop down field using `<select>` tag.How can I populate the select with data (which should be matching from xml file) from the xml file , so that I can select values using up and down arrow keys.Please advice me giving sample code as I am very beginner to php and Jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: yes. I am using ajax to populate div with xml data as given the tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp. But I cannot select values using arrow keys as `div` is given here instead of dropdown. How can I change ?

Comment: you need alot of code to make a modern div driven dropdown list.as u need to add eventlisteners to click,mousewheel,keypress ...

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to populate a `<select>`

it's written to work on modern browsers.. polyfill needs more code.

replace *x.xml* with the search url.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script>
var
x=function(a,b,c){c=new XMLHttpRequest;c.open('GET',a);c.onload=b;c.send()};
 x('x.xml',function(){
  var
  xml=this.responseXML.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('ProjectName'),
  xmll=xml.length,
  a=[],
  sel=document.createElement('select');
  while(xmll--){
   var txt=xml[xmll].textContent;
   a[xmll]='<option value="'+txt.trim()+'">'+txt+'</option>';
  }
  sel.innerHTML=a.join('');
  document.body.appendChild(sel);
 });
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide u a neat solution using Jquery UI auto completion

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
minglength:2 // Just to prevent many useless requests
source: "livesearch.php"
select : function (e,ui){
window.href=ui.item.val()}

 });
```

Now the php side

```
$q=$_GET["term"]; Note that Jquery sends the search query as GET using term variable

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
// Some Code for hint note that it must return a json or array of json for many results
}
    echo $hint;
?>
```

The Json structure is like that

```
{"value":"The value you want","label":"The display name you want to show useless in ur case"}
```